# Fixing writeRaster script for writing multiple .tif layers

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have this rasterbrick/stack that I need to write individual files into a folder. I have done this task several times before but some of the recent improvements to `terra` and `raster` have rendered some of my codes unusable and I'm not sure where the problems are because the error messages are not intuitive.

Here's my code:

```
writeRaster(myraster, file.path("D:/...filepath/", 
                    names(myraster)), bylayer=T, format='GTiff', overwrite = T)
```

> Error in file(fn, "rb") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(fn, "rb") :
> cannot open file 'C:...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEvVX4G\raster\r_tmp_2023-09-25_235519.636784_15272_51613.gri': No such file or directory

So following the error message, I went and deleted all the folders in my `Temp` folder except those in use. The code then started to throw a totally different error message.

> Error: [writeStart] cannot overwrite existing file

Here's the [test data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c5AZS9onKUOzNoIVw3py3QFIRxITCjZ_?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you provide some of the data and the output of names(baseline_data)?

Comment: I don't think it's a data issue. Any data should do. Judging by the lack of suggestions for a seemingly simple issue over several days, I'm guessing it might be a bug.

Comment: Please see - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
library(raster)
dir.create("d:/...filepath", FALSE, FALSE)

b <- brick(nrow=5, ncol=5, nl=3)
values(b) <- 1:75
names(b) <- c("A", "B", "C")
x <- writeRaster(b, file.path("D:/...filepath/", names(b)),
             format="GTiff", bylayer=T, overwrite=T)
x
#class      : RasterStack 
#dimensions : 5, 5, 25, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 72, 36  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#names      :  A,  B,  C 
#min values :  1, 26, 51 
#max values : 25, 50, 75 

filename(x[[1]])
#[1] "D:\\...filepath\\A.tif"
```

Note that `filetype` is an argument for `terra::writeRaster`. But as you are using a RasterBrick, you are using `raster::writeRaster` and there the equivalent argument is called `format`. To avoid confusion you can leave the argument out and append ".tif" to filename instead.

Comment: the issue was getting the script to write `.tif` files. In fact, my second code can write `.grid` files just as yours did. It seems that `writeRaster` is not honouring the `filetype` argument.

Comment: You said that your second approach also failed. I have updated my answer for .tif.

Comment: It still didn't work for me even with the namespace. `raster::writeRaster` and `filetype` changed to `format`. The error message here: `Error in .startGDALwriting(x, filename, gdal = options, format = filetype,  : 
  formal argument "sources" matched by multiple actual arguments`.

Comment: The point is that my example works. Can you create a reproducible example that creates this error?  Using the namespace `raster::` does not change anything because writeRaster is a generic (but the error message shows you are using the version defined by raster). Are your packages up to date?

Comment: Yes, my packages are up to date. I also did a fresh installation of `R` and `Rstudio`. I have now added the data to my question.

Comment: I removed that because the file R object you provided only works on your computer (where the file with the data are, or used to be).  We need a reproducible example; that is. create some data with code; there are 1000s of examples on this site that show how to do that.

Comment: I didn't know that about `RDS` files. I recreated the data and tried `dput` but I couldn't reconstruct the data and does not have the identifiable structure that is common with dataframe.  Not sure if it's meant to be used with rasters. I have uploaded the data as a `NetCDF` file instead.

Comment: What we need is a reproducible example that creates the error.

Comment: Robert, I'm not certain what you are expecting as the information I'm getting about reproducible examples seems in line with what I have produced in my question. The code that I'm using is identical to yours and the error message is as presented in my question `Error in file(fn, "rb") : cannot open the connection In addition...`  So, the only unknown is my computer info, which is a Windows 11.  I note that the code works on your system. So, I'm not certain what's left.

Comment: Then please edit your question to show *exactly* what you do to get this error. Again, my example works for me, and you are not saying it does not work for you. So I would need to see what you do to break this. Perhaps you do not have the disk space?

Comment: Yes, I have enough disk space; more than 2T and I have tried writing the files to other storage devices. I have edited the question to clarify exactly what prompted the error. To troubleshoot the error, I deleted folders in my `temp` folder and I now have a different error message from the same code `Error: [writeStart] cannot overwrite existing file`.  The lack of consistency in the error messages is baffling.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I get the same error running the code snippet above copy and pasted directly. It works if I subset it to only one layer, e.g "writeRaster(b[[3]]...". But it throws the following if I try to do more than one.

"Error in .startGDALwriting(x, filename, gdal = options, ...) :
formal argument "sources" matched by multiple actual arguments"

raster_3.6-20 sp_1.6-1

terra_1.7-29 ("loaded via a namespace (and not attached)")

R version 4.2.3

Note I work for a  gov't agency and cannot install new R versions until they have been approved by our IT staff.

update... I ran this on my personal MacOS machine with R 4.3.2 and it worked fine, so probably a version issue. Maybe a Windows issue.

Falling back on a good old fashioned for loop.

```
for (i in seq(1:length(names(b)))) {
  writeRaster(b[[i]], file.path("E:...", names(b[[i]])),format="GTiff", bylayer=T, overwrite=T)
}
```